# Pellet collides with hanging block, what is the velocity of pellet? Two different methods of answering with different answers which is correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, momentum

[image: This is the question in full]

There are two different methods to solve this question and both of them make sense to me yet they give different answers:

Method 1:

The energy of the system at the start and at the end must be the same, therefore the kinetic energy of the pellet at the beginning is the same as the gravitational potential energy of rising both the pellet and the block by 0.63 meters.

KE = 1/2 * 0.0088 * v^2

GPE = 0.4588 * 9.81 * 0.63 = 2.84

KE = GPE

v^2 = 644

v = 25 m/s

Method 2:

The GPE of the block and the pellet at its max height (0.63m) is equal to the initial KE it has, immediately after the pellet impacts.

GPE = KE

2.84 = 1/2 * 0.4588 * V(both)^2

V(both)^2 = 12.2

V(both) = 3.49 m/s

Then you set up a conservation of momentum equation.

0.0088 * v = 0.4588 * 3.49

v = 182 m/s

As you can see they give me wildly different answers but I can't see anything wrong with either of them.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: It is an inelastic collision method one is incorrect

Comment: This system is called a "ballistic pendulum" (because this arrangement is a traditional method of measuring muzzle velocities), and we have several questions about them on the site already: https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=ballistic+pendulum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This I'm not 100% percent about, it's just a hunch, but I hope it solves the problem. Moving something both horizontally and vertically at the same time consumes more energy than it'll take to do just one of them, so the potential energy isn't exactly equal to the body's initial kinetic energy. As an approximation of the vector resultant of the velocity vector as it changes throughout the arc, draw a vector line from the CG of the stationary block mass to the CG at max potential, that gives us an estimate of the direction. Carefully measure this angle $theta$ to the horizontal with something like a protactor with the hope that the image above is drawn to scale. Now do $ mgh=\frac 12 m sin^2v$. The resulting $v$ calculated should (hopefully) be the intitial velocity of both mass just after impact. Use this as $v_{both}$ in the conservation of momentum equation and that should be it.

A similar case to this one is an object in a 2D parabolic trajectory motion and the potential energy at its apogee isn't zero because it's still moving horizontally. So the total kinetic energy of motions at an angle isn't always equals the potential energy because they're simultaneously moving in two different dimensions.

Note: I've never encountered something like this, and I can't assure you the above method will provide an accurate result, but it's worth the shot.